# How to construct a model to satisfy first order logic sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I'm studying for a Logic exam and I'm currently working through past paper. However I'm finding it difficult to understand the following question.

I have been asked to:

Construct $L$-sentences formalizing the following:

i) $R(x, y)$ is a linear order with left endpoint $b$ and right endpoint $c$;

ii) $f(x)$ is a injective (i.e. one-to-one) function which has exactly two objects which bear $R(x, y)$ to $b$ in its range.

And to then:

Construct a model whose domain contains four objects in which the sentences i) and ii) you constructed are satisfied.

I'm finding it difficult to find such a module though. $b$ is a left endpoint, so surely there cannot be two objects with bear $R(x, y)$ to $b$. The two sentences seem to contradict each other, and I don't know how to construct such a model.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is that the exact phrasing?  The phrase "bear R(x, y) to b" does not make sense...

Comment: Yeah, it's the exact phrasing. I copied and pasted it straight out of the exam paper

Comment: Does "bear" have some particular technical meaning in this course?  If not, my conclusion would just be that this problem is indecipherable and must have some kind of error in the statement.

Comment: I've never actually heard my lecturer use the term "bear" before, however I've seen him write it in another past paper. I'm guessing "a bears R to b" means R(a,b) holds, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Try interpreting "a bears R to b" as $R(b,a)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would work. Thank you.